# configure X axis values

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to build a chart based on Series values.

```
ts=myshare['Close'].tail(3650)
```

It is working as expected but the x-axis is shown as 500 -1000 - 1500 - ...
The index values of ts object are nothing but datetime values and I will like to see those values on X axis.
I tried to loop through the ts.index but it does not seem to work.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(ts)
#plt.xticks([myin for myin in ts.index], size='small')
```

How do I show the index values of the Series on x axis?

Comment: That worked. What was I doing wrong? How does it differ?

Comment: Matplotlib functions don't "know" about pandas objects, they just treat them as numpy arrays. That's why pandas objects have `plot` that use matplotlib to draw a plot but in a way that exploits the additional information in the index, column names (for DataFrames), etc.